# JIRA issue read/unread status support

Tags: jira

Is there any way in JIRA to track issue read/unread status in the way the email clients do? I want to be able to filter modified but not viewed issues.

Comment: I think that Alex implied that this is done for each viewer of an issue. So it would likely be a client-side thing, perhaps using Speakeasy. I guess you could also intercept ViewIssue on the server side and record the issue id and user in an Active Objects database. But nothing out of the box, for sure.

Comment: How do you know read/unread status of an issue from Jira Rest API

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any built-in mechanism for that, AFAIK.

However, there is a plugin called `behaviours`, I heard it could be done using this add-on.